# How to scroll down to the position of a found and highlighted pattern in codemirror editor in a webix application

Tags: javascript, codemirror, webix

In my Webix application, I have embedded a codemirror-editor to write JavaScript into it. Is there a way to scroll upto the position of a found and highlighted pattern when I do a search using browser's Ctrl+F or by any other means ?

I came to know about an add-on search/jump-to-line.js from http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_search

and also about below way to achieve this(cm is a codemirror reference) :

```
cm.scrollIntoView(what: {line, ch}|{left, top, right, bottom}|{from, to}|null, ?margin: number)
```

However, not quite sure how to use them. I am including the snippet of the code I have written so far below along with its snippet link. 
Snippet link : http://webix.com/snippet/7acca905

The code is included below :

```
webix.codebase = "http://cdn.webix.com/components/codemirror/";
var editor1 = {
id: "editor1",
view: "codemirror-editor",
mode: "javascript",
value: "",
height: 200
};

var editor2 = {
id: "editor2",
view: "codemirror-editor",
mode: "javascript",
value: "",
height: 200

};

var ed1 = {id:"editor1",  value: "Editor-I" };
var ed2 = {id:"editor2",  value: "Editor-II" };

var op = [ed1, ed2];

var views = {
animate: false,
cells: [ 
editor1, editor2
]
}; 

webix.ui({
    container: "mydiv",
    rows: [
    {view: "tabbar", 
    id: "tabview",
    options:op,
    multiview:{ keepViews:true }

  },
  views,
 {height: 300},

]
});
```

The HTML part associated to it :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.webix.com/components/codemirror/codemirror.js"></script>
<div id = "mydiv" style="margin-top:30px;"></div>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get codemirror object like

```
var cm = $$("editor1").getEditor();
```

Unfortunately, it seems version of code mirror from cdn.webix.com is outdated and doesn't support scrollIntoView API

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you please elaborate a bit that where and how should we use this code ?